# My xamarin.ios project does not find the provisioning list

Tags: xamarin.ios, app-store

I'm about to publish my first APP on IOS.
I stopped because visual studio 2017 (windows10) does not find the provisioning list (see image) in IOS Bundle Signing.
[image]
what could be the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved.
Usual refresh problems. Close and reopen Visual Studio, reconnect the MAC etc.